# Simple ajax rails 3 call troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

So i'm trying to make a simple ajax call in rails 3 but can't get the ajax to return properly.  I think I'm missing something obvious but I've been trying for the past 3 hours so I figured it's time to ask.

I'm attempting the ajax call on the index page of the post model which is supposed to return search results.

My posts_controller.rb for the index action looks like this.

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js #ajax call
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

My index.html.erb (which contains the search text field and div where (ajax) results are to be returned looks like this

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => "get", :remote => true do %>
 <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search",  :class => "btn", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<div id="posts">
    <%= render @posts %>
</div>
```

My _post.html.erb looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="well well-small"><%= post.title %></td>
        <td class="well"><%= post.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <br />
</table>
```

My index.js.erb looks like this

```
$("#posts").html("<%= escape_javscript(render :partial => "new" ) %>");
```

and my post.rb model page looks like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :content, :title
  def self.search (search)

    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all) 
    end
  end

end
```

Sorry there has to be so much code just wanted to show everything relevant. For some reason my search results aren't being updated with ajax. When I remove the :remote => true from the form in index.html.erb and remove the index.js.erb file, the search results are returned fine(without ajax) so my search functionality is not the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help. As always if you give me a good answer, I will accept it as the right one.

Comment: did you try debugging it with chrome developer tools? just in case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not re-rendering your new collection of posts, you're rendering the 'new' partial!

Try this instead on your index.js.erb file:

```
$("#posts").html("<%= j(render :collection => @posts ) %>");
```

Do not change anything else from what you posted and it should work.

Comment: Pedro, thanks for the response. I appreciate it. I tried this method leaving my code exactly the same but changing the index.js.erb as you said. It works fine without ajax but with ajax, it still does not work.

Comment: Any stack trace, either from the server terminal or the Chrome inspector console (assuming you're using Chrome) would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, after your ajax request you want update your view: so I would try something like this in your **posts_controller.rb**:

```
format.js do 
    render :update do |page|
        page.replace_html 'id_of_your_refreshed_element', :partial => 'partial_content_refreshed'
    end
end
```

It should work. Your partial_view will take in consideration your new *@posts* variable.

I hope It will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I put the 5 extra lines of code you told me. Just to show you, the important line looks like this... page.replace_html 'posts', :partial =>'index'                       But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to refresh your **posts**, I'll do like this: _page.replace_html 'posts', :partial =>'partial_view_containing_posts'_ and in my #posts _div_ I' ll put <%= render :partial => 'partial_view_containing_posts' %>. In fact, the page.replace_html will update html your _#posts_ div with the _partial_view_containing_posts_. The _@posts_ variable will take new values and your view will use this variable. I maybe don't understand your objectives.

Comment: render :update has been deprecated as well as these javascript helpers (replace_html, etc), I suggest you to not follow this answer.